# Sed Having a Space in Regex

Tags: linux, sed

I am having difficulty using sed to replace

```
proxy: ''
```

with

```
proxy: 'https://link.com:8099'
```

in a file

I have the following command (see below) but it is giving me

```
proxy: https://link.com:8099''
```

with both quotes after the url.

```
sed 's@proxy: ''@proxy: 'http://link.com:8099'@'<test.txt > test1.txt
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am doing this in RHEL and need to do this within chef.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
echo "proxy: ''" |sed 's#\x27\x27#\x27https://link.com:8099\x27#g'
proxy: 'https://link.com:8099'
```

Why it works:
We use a different delimiter `#` so we don't need to escape `/`
Instead of a million escapes to `''` we use the hex ascii code of them = `\x27`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify double single quote `''` with `'\'\''`.

You can do like the following :

```
sed -r 's/(proxy:\s+)('\'\'')/\1'\'https:\\/\\/link.com:8099\''/g' test.txt > test1.txt
```

The first group is the `proxy:` text following by the single quotes to replace

Comment: Our difference is a couple of iseconds !! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "proxy: ''" | sed -e "s@proxy: ''@proxy: 'http://blah'@"
proxy: 'http://blah'
```

Do I miss something in the question?